# Running .NET from ColdFusion

Tags: .net, coldfusion

I'm having issues running a DLL written in C# from ColdFusion.

ColdFusion Code:

```
<cfset dll = ExpandPath('./RemoteDraftingDLL.dll')>
<cfobject type=".NET" name="testing" class="Remote.Macro" assembly="#dll#">
<cfset output = testing.TestMethod()>
<cfoutput>#output#</cfoutput>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Could not find the DotNet class.  
The assembly might not be registered with the DotNetSide.
```

It sounds like I need to register the DLL some where within the ColdFusion administration page but I'm not sure where or how?

Comment: Nevermind...Issue was resolved. We just needed to restart the Coldfusion server.

Comment: @sergii I answered by own post 3 hours before he ansewered. However, he did add some great additional information so I will accept his answer.

Comment: I've seen that, but answer in comments doesn't really count here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everytime you change a DLL you need to restart ColdFusion. Including the initial time you place the DLL on the server and everytime the DLL is updated.

I think it would be nice if they allowed you to programmatically update the DLL register.

Comment: That seems like a real hassel when debugging...I agree with you that it would be nice to programmatically update the DLL register.